# emplace and default constructors

Tags: c++, stl, perfect-forwarding, emplace

Given the following code, I was surprised that `try_emplace` could not work out to use the default constructor demonstrated in the first line of the main function, instead complaining there is no matching function call to `Element::Element(double, double)`. Have I misunderstood the way the compiler creates default constructors or the usage of `try_emplace`? I can of course get this code to work by defining an all parameter ctors for `Element`, but this seems redundant.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct Element
{    
    double a;
    double b;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Element e {2.0, 3.0};

    std::map<std::string, Element> my_map;
    my_map.try_emplace("hello", 2.0, 3.0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't generate c'tor s with parameters, and `try_emplace` will only try to call a c'tor (no aggregate initialisation).

Comment: But then where does the definition for `Element e{2.0, 3.0}` come from?

Comment: @Madden Element is an aggregate (a POD actually), for which brace initialization is supported, even without any constructor. I think that this is a deficiency in the standard, and it should have had a special code in emplace_back for aggregates. This would have been more consistent and less surprising.

Comment: For unknown reason the STL has poor support for aggregates!

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can opt to not define any user-defined ctors in `Element` but rather use those that are still defined no matter what (unless explicitly deleted):

```
    my_map.try_emplace("hello", Element{2.0, 3.0});
```

Comment: Will this method entail a copy of the Element object?

Comment: @Madden - Yes. But seeing as this type is a simple trivially copiable aggregate, it likely won't do any worse than forwarding two doubles. Don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: Sure, but this was more of a simple example - in practice I intend to do a lot of emplacing and with much more complex/larger objects. I will define specific constructors to make sure I avoid the copy

Comment: @Madden Such templated functions usually forward their arguments, so if you have proper overloads accepting rvalue references, they should be called.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the fact that `emplace` methods attempt to instantiate elements with parentheses, not by aggregate initialization. You can verify that

```
Element e(2.0, 3.0);
```

fails to compile, because there is no such constructor (`Element e{2.0, 3.0}` bypasses such a constructor call). But this is what `emplace` tries to do. To fix this, you can add an appropriate constructor:

```
struct Element
{
    Element(double a, double b) : a(a), b(b) {}

    double a;
    double b;
};
```